# Interaction.defaults on specific vectorLayer and added after the map is already initialized

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm in trouble with ol.interaction.defaults().extend(). I hope you can help me :)

I re-implemented the [Drag feature example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/examples/drag-features.html?q=drag) 
 On a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DhraSCjmT0zA06oVE9P7?p=preview) for test.

```
var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new app.Drag()]);

var map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: dragInteraction,
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
        url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.jsonp'
      })
    }),
    layerA,
    layerB
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

//map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
```

I have to issues :

1. I want to enable the dragInteraction only for the layerA (not
   layerB); how can I do that ?
2. I want to add this interaction AFTER
       that the map has been created. But wen I try, there is an execution
       error. I don't know if its possible to ovveride defaults interaction once the map has been created ?

I searched on OL3-Dev & API doc, but didn't found the correct solution.

notes :

- I have to keep separate vector Layer in variables
- I really want to add the interaction AFTER, for better architecture design.
- My goal is to retrieve the coordinate of the dragget overlay/feature.

Thks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to enable the dragInteraction only for the layerA (not layerB); how can I do that ?

You can always add a new interaction after the initialization of the map with:

```
map.addInteraction(new app.Drag());
```

> I want to add this interaction AFTER that the map has been created. But wen I try, there is an execution error. I don't know if its possible to ovveride defaults interaction once the map has been created ?

In the drag interaction you are using [`map.forEachFeatureAtPixel`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) which takes a parameter `layerFilter`. You can use it like so:

```
var layerFilter = function(layer) {
  return layer === layerA;
}

var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
      return feature;
    }, this, layerFilter, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like suggestion above. Give a name for layer, implement a layer filter and add the interaction after the map creation.

I forked your [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjbsRkDTXfMWkg5fRcVU?p=preview) as an example.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the forked example ! :) (i can't upvote right know, I don't have enough reputation, i'll upvote when it will be possible!)